# getting queue name in PUT API Exit (MQ_PUT_EXIT)

Tags: api, exit, ibm-mq

In Put MQ API Exit (before or after) is there any way to get the name of the target queue (i.e. the queue against which "put" call has been invoked).

I tried inquiring on `Hobj` parameter, but got an error saying object has not been opened with Inquiry option (which is a valid possibility).

I also checked `ResolvedQName` field of `pPutMsgOpts` parameter, but that was blank.

Is there any other means of getting the target queue name? Any idea would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The names of the resolved queue manager and resolved queue are returned in the [object descriptor](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/fr13780_.htm) accessible during the [`MQXR_AFTER`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/fg14950_.htm) call for the PUT1 or the OPEN.

Have a look at the sample program `amqsaxe0.c and you will see the following function signatures:

```
MQ_OPEN_EXIT OpenAfter;

void MQENTRY OpenAfter   ( PMQAXP    pExitParms
                         , PMQAXC    pExitContext
                         , PMQHCONN  pHconn
                         , PPMQOD    ppObjDesc
                         , PMQLONG   pOptions
                         , PPMQHOBJ  ppHobj
                         , PMQLONG   pCompCode
                         , PMQLONG   pReason
                         )


MQ_PUT1_EXIT Put1After;

void MQENTRY Put1After   ( PMQAXP    pExitParms
                         , PMQAXC    pExitContext
                         , PMQHCONN  pHconn
                         , PPMQOD    ppObjDesc
                         , PPMQMD    ppMsgDesc
                         , PPMQPMO   ppPut1MsgOpts
                         , PMQLONG   pBufferLength
                         , PPMQVOID  ppBuffer
                         , PMQLONG   pCompCode
                         , PMQLONG   pReason
                         )
```

The object descriptor in the before call has the object name specified by the application.  The same structure in the after call has the name of the QMgr and queue that were resolved during the call.  Since the PUT1 performs the open, put and close in one step it must resolve the queue name.  However in the case of separate open, put(, put...), close calls the name resolution occurs only once during the open.

Please see the samples in `/var/mqm/samp` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\tools\c\Samples` for the `amqsaxe0.c` program.

Comment: Thanks Rob for the quick response. much appreciated! I am however not sure how to access object descriptor. From the method signature of PUT API exit it appears only handle to object (&Hobj) is available and not object descriptor. MQ_PUT_EXIT (&ExitParms, &ExitContext, &Hconn, &Hobj, &pMsgDesc, &pPutMsgOpts, &BufferLength, &pBuffer, &CompCode, &Reason)

Comment: My apologies for the brief response.  I've updated it with what is hopefully a better explanation.

Comment: Thanks Rob! it was very insightful.  I was trying with put exit in scenario of separate (open, put, close) calls; and wanted to restrict put_exit to a single queue (among many queues present under a QM).By default it seems a registered exit gets called for all the queues under a QM. so if we want to restrict put_exit to a single queue how can we do that? is there a correlation between open and put exit call? can we compare object handles and expect them to be the same ?

Comment: I'm sure you can do that because [SupportPac MA0W](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMA0W) does it.  ;-)  I believe that you will need to monitor the open calls and save object handles of interest.  Note that multiple opens on the same queue will return unique object handles. (If it didn't, then transactions would commit across all apps with the queue open, which would be bad!)  By the way, if you haven't already found MA0W, have a look.  It might save you writing your own exit.

Comment: MA0W looks interesting, I will give it a try. although i intend to do more than tracing. So i will try your suggestion of saving object handles of interest. I see MA0W' has the filtering feature by specifying "Target queue name and process name to be traced". Thanks a lot again!